# How to login with Keycloak to React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak

I do not want to use the form provided by Keycloak (different company reasons), but instead create our own login page in React. I could login with it using the direct access grant flow and get the auth and refresh tokens. However, I would like to use the Keycloak Javascript adapter to check if a user is logged in, and it doesn't provide a function to run the check based on the token (only if it knows that you are already authenticated).

I could make social login work with this adapter and silent check-sso works well with it, I just want it to work with simple logins as well.

Can this be done with the keycloak-js adapter or do I have to implement the token checking myself?

Answer (score 0):

Forcing the usage of the the direct access grant is a pretty dangerous company reason. A company reason, that introduces huge security risks.

See:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_resource_owner_password_credentials_flow

It would be MUCH safer to implement a new login page as a Keycloak theme.
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_themes

Much safer. But still: When you use external libraries (like react) from whatever source you may download them (like npm), on your login page, you better make really sure you can trust ever bit and byte of what you pack to your login page. Because no, you can not trust NPM or any system in the delivery chain of your dependencies. NPM does not guarantee, that the code you add to your project, is really the code you see on github.

In short, that's one good reason why you really should stick to a plain, easy, default login page where every code path is 100% understood. Without dependencies or external code. So your client applications never see any passwords and no external code can steal them.